# Assistance with PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I don't usually use regular expressions, hence my question. I need a regex to match the following:

```
'{any-string}'.
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: It might be a good idea to read a tutorial about regular expressions so that you actually understand them and don't just copy and paste the top-rated answer into your code. A little knowledge is a very dangerous thing. Parsing strings can be very tricky with lots of edge cases to watch out for.

Comment: Should the quotes be part of the match or did you just add them for "clarity"?

Comment: match {any-string} and then...?

Comment: are there allowed to be more curly brackets within the {}? And should quotes and the period be part of the string to match? Or are you looking to match `{any string}`? Some example matched/non-matched strings would be helpful.

Comment: @Mark Byers - I added the quotes for clarity.
@stereofrog - Not that that was asked, but match {any-string} and replace all the instances in the source read in using file_get_contents().
@incrediman - No, other curly brackets are not allowed inside the most outer pair of {}. The quotes and period should not be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple expression would be:

```
/{(.*?)}/
```

If you expect more complex strings (for example, some kind of escape sequence where the `{` and `}` characters are allowed within the string) it could be more complex. For instance, with a `\` (backslash) escape sequence:

```
/{((?:\\.|[^}])*)}/
```

Edit: That's not tested, but the general idea is that the expression will swallow any character following the escape rather than ensuring it isn't the closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

To replace anything in `{ }` with what `file_get_contents` returns you can do:

```
$page = file_get_contents('some_file_name or some_url');
$str = '.....{...}....';
$str = preg_replace('/{[^}]*}/',"$page",$str);
```